# Foreman with Puppet node Net::HTTPNotFound Error

Tags: puppet, theforeman

I have installed foreman (v1.9.0) on a RHEL 7.1 VM as per the official documentation.

My current environment consists of:

- 1 x Puppet master/foreman
- 2 x agents (RHEL 6.5 & 7)

Foreman is configured as the ENC which will service 9 environments (inc production).
A smart proxy has been configured in foreman for the foreman/puppetmaster.

There were no issues on the agents in generating the CSR and getting it signed by the puppet master.

When I run the puppet agent on a remote machine with the command

```
puppet agent --no-daemonize --server <FQDN> --trace
```

I get the following errors

> Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent will continue:
>
> Warning: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to find < agent FQDN> via exec: Execution of '/etc/puppet/node.rb < agent FQDN>' returned 1:

Running the referenced command on the puppet master

```
sudo -u puppet /etc/puppet/node.rb <agent FQDN>
```

Returns the error:

> Error retrieving node < agent FQDN> Net::HTTPNotFound
>
> Check Foreman's /var/log/foreman/production.log for more information.

Researching this error on the web 
"[Foreman with puppet node.rb error 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649563/foreman-with-puppet-node-rb-error-404-not-found)"
provides the standard response of the puppet master is not aware (DNS, /etc/hosts) of the agent.
In my case this is not the issue as running the same node.rb command against the puppetmaster returns the same error. A simple ping test confirms that DNS is correctly setup.

There are no logs generated in /var/log/foreman/production.log (inc debug) when this fails, although there is a http 404 error generated in /var/log/httpd/foreman-ssl_access_ssl.log

> < IP> - - [30/Sep/2015:15:13:29 +1000] GET /node/< agent FQDN>?format=yml HTTP/1.1" 404 48 "-" "Ruby"

node.rb references foreman.yaml which is correct in relation to the listed entries I can confirm like:

- :url:
- :ssl_ca:
- :ssl_cert:
- :ssl_key:
- etc

It is also the default file generated by the install process with no changes.

The agents are in foreman, but to achieve that once I configured puppet.conf and generated/signed the agent certs I ran the command

```
puppet agent -t <puppet master FQDN>
```

the agents were not imported into foreman until I manually ran the command

```
foreman-rake puppet:import:hosts_and_facts
```

calling one of the hosts in foreman and then clicking on 'YAML' shows correct information for each agent.

I have even pulled the information out of the certificates using openssl to confirm that they are correct.

UPDATE:

I have run the command

`curl -k https://< Puppet Master FQDN>/foreman`

This returns the output

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://< Puppet Master FQDN>/foreman/users/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

This generates the log entry in 
~/foreman/production.log

> 2015-10-01 10:04:57 [app] [I]
>   |
>   | Starged GET "/foreman/" for < PUPPET MASTER IP> at 2015-10-01 10:04:57 +1000
>   2015-10-01 10:04:57 [app] [I] Processing by DashboardController#index as */*
>   2015-10-01 10:04:57 [app] [I]Redirected to https://< PUPPET MASTER>/foreman/users/login
>   2015-10-01 10:04:57 [app] [I] Filter chain halted as :require_login
>   rendered or redirected 
>   2015-10-01 10:04:57 [app] [I]Completed 302 Found in 7ms (Active Record: 0.6ms)

While in ~/httpd/foreman-ssl_access_ssl.log I get this

> < PUPPET MASTER IP> - - [01/Oct/2015:10:05:26 +1000] "GET /foreman/ HTTP/1.1" 302 129 "-" "curl/7.29.0"

Other relevant log entries in the same log would be

> < PUPPET MASTER IP> - - [01/Oct/2015:09:53:28 +1000] "POST /api/hosts/facts /HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "-" "Ruby"
>
> < PUPPET MASTER IP> - - [01/Oct/2015:09:53:28 +1000] "GET /node/< PUPPET MASTER>?format=yml HTTP/1.1" 404 52 "-" "Ruby"

So the question to ask is what can I do to the Puppet/Foreman HTTP config to resolve the 404 errors

Comment: No production.log entries suggests the request only gets as far as Apache and not Foreman.  You mention the web UI works, but check `curl -k https://puppet master fqdn` from the master itself returns a login redirect, and see if /var/log/httpd/foreman-ssl_error_ssl.log or /var/log/httpd/error_log contains any logging.

Comment: I have updated the original question with the additional data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the ENC script is requesting paths at the root of the web server (/api) while Foreman itself is hosted at a sub-URI (/foreman/).  It should be hitting `/foreman/api/hosts/facts`, `/foreman/node/` etc, which is why Apache's returning a 404, but Foreman isn't seeing and logging the request.

You can change the URL that node.rb uses in /etc/puppet/foreman.yaml, via the `:url:` setting.  Add the `/foreman` suffix here.

Alternatively if you used the Foreman installer then you could re-run it with `--puppet-server-foreman-url=https://example.com/foreman` which should do the same thing.

Comment: I will try your first option, although from memory (I am not at currently at work) the :url: setting includes /foreman. When I installed foreman i used the option --foreman-url=https://example.com/foreman. I will also attempt the re-run of the installer with the option --puppet-server-foreman-url=https://fqdn/foreman.

Comment: I have reinstalled/configured using your option of --puppet-server-foreman-url and it works. I had only used --foreman-foreman-url